# Soundcloud track stream URL returns 403 error Signature does not match

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

When trying to use the returned url from sound cloud, the response sometimes indicates an issue with the signature.

For example, this will return an error for invalid signature:
https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/8ekeDCuVw9Fe.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522039866f9bc34968a8ed18ed974bfe4155532adb094f3250532a33fbdc229b885cce1e1a3578d4916ca0e43&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNIGGLK7XA7YZSNQ&Expires=1424912897&Signature=XZ5adww3M/3TLhw+lCaPqeDt8Nk=

Can we get a valid signature from the API on all calls?  This is returned straight from the API, so I'm hoping some soundcloud peeps can weigh in on this...

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I'm suddenly getting 403 on http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/220276535?client_id=2d011b71271df73d0e0e68b431f48252&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200  which had been fine for the last year...